# Migrate FUNCTION (Postgres 9.1) to Postgres 8.0 (AWS Redshift)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I was looking for a way to search a specific value in all tables and all columns in the Postgres and I found this.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns(
    needle text,
    haystack_tables name[] default '{}',
    haystack_schema name[] default '{}'
)
RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
AS $$
begin
  FOR schemaname,tablename,columnname IN
      SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
      FROM information_schema.columns c
      JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
        (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
      WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(haystack_tables) OR haystack_tables='{}')
        AND (c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema) OR haystack_schema='{}')
        AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L',
       schemaname,
       tablename,
       columnname,
       needle
    ) INTO rowctid;
    IF rowctid is not null THEN
      RETURN NEXT;
    END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But the problem is: I want to execute it in the AWS Redshift, that is using a Postgres 8.0 and this code only works in Postgres 9.1+.

Someone can help me to migrate this function to become compatible with Postgres 8.0 or inform another way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can't. Quote from [Unsupported PostgreSQL Features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html): "*- Table functions*"